# CakePHP 3.x Merge Find Results

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.6

I am currently grabbing two result sets from two different tables with the same column structure.

Is it possible to do something like array_merge on these two sets of data and merge them into one set so that I can paginate the results in the view?

Comment: You should probably look into using a union query.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to use CakePHP's `Hash` class and `combine` function.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html